# converting c# to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, powershell

I'm developing a program to execute powershell from .net app. I found a sample but it uses c# so I'm changing the code to vb.net but I don't know how change the following line:

```
Collection<psobject /> results = pipeline.Invoke();
```

any advice is welcome.

ps. the full code is here, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C

Comment: google "c# to vb". http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: You're going the wrong way! Vb.net -> c# good. Reverse = bad.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, I'm agree with you however use vb.net is a requirement of the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the / is a mistake in the article.

```
dim results as Collection(of psobject) = pipeline.Invoke()
```

Maybe "collection" means that you can use an Enumerable to store the results.

```
dim results as IEnumerable(of psobject) = pipeline.Invoke()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [code converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) such as the free one from telerik. The converter did hickup on the 
`<psobject />` . removing the / gives you.

```
Dim results As Collection(Of psobject) = pipeline.Invoke()
```

Answer (score 3):

The type `Collection<PSObject>` is a C# generic type.  In VB.Net a generic type uses `(Of ...)` instead of `<...>` so the translation here is `Collection(Of PSObject)`.

```
Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = pipeline.Invoke()
```

Another option here is to simply omit the type and let type inference do it's work assuming you have `Option Infer` on

```
Dim results = pipeline.Invoke()
```

Comment: @JaredPat, I got Error 1 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection' has no type parameters and so cannot have type arguments. So I applied the Jonathan's recomendation using IEnumerable and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @m0dest0 ahh, that's because it's confusing `Collection` with the VB runtime type.  Jonathan's suggestion will definitely work.  Another option is to fully qualify the type name or use my second suggestion of type inference.  Either way, glad it's working for you

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in his text. There's no such construct in c#:

```
Collection<psobject />
```

Download his source and take it from there.